# Layout messed up when using AdmPanel in TYPO3

Tags: typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

When I active AdmPanel and trying to use the edit functions like >Display edit icons< and/or >Display edit panels< the layout messes up. The Edit Icons are huge shown all over the entire page.

Back in the days there was bug that the CSS wasn't included, but that's not the case. adminpanel.css is present. But beside it looks like all the elements doesn't have any css definition at all.

I couldn't find anyone experiencing the same issue and also tried other installation, but it's everywhere the same. Does anyone have an idea what am I missing here?

Comment: I assume that the CSS (+ JS?) of your site has an effect on the admin panel, which is plain HTML added to the end of your normal page code and so styled with the global CSS as anything else. If you have multiple installations you might use the same base CSS on all installations.

Comment: That's what I thought in the first place, but there are no styles at all applied to any of the classes or elements. Shouldn't there be any definition like where the Edit-Button is placed, the width, the height, you name it. There are no definitions at all. There are no defintion for class .typo3-editPanel, .typo3-editPanel-btn-group, etc. But there should be or not?

Comment: maybe your concatenated(!) (and compressed?) CSS is broken? if one of your CSS files is invalid it could make following CSSs invalid too and so the CSS of the adminpanel is not available.

Comment: That what I deactived first. :) No compressing or concatenating. That thing makes me crazy.

Comment: try to find out whether the CSS for the adminpanel can be loaded. inspect the network panel of your browser and also inspect the console log whether there is a broken javascript which terminates JS execution, which migt be needed for the admin panel